# Order a hash/array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to order a Productlist (:product) based on the units sold (:quantity):

```
<% Sale.where(brand: current_user.brand).group(:product).by_day.sum(:quantity).order(:quantity => :desc).limit(10).each do |p, c| %>
 <tr>
  <td><strong><%= p %></strong></td>
  <td><%= c %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

This produces an error:

> undefined method `order' for #Hash:....

Shouldn't the order method just consider the field quantity and not the whole hash?

**Solution:**

```
<% Sale.where(brand: current_user.brand).group(:product).by_day.sum(:quantity).sort_by{|product,quantity|  -quantity}.each do |product,quantity| %>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can use Ruby `sort_by` as `-` sign is used for order using `desc`:

```
Sale.where(brand: current_user.brand).group(:product).by_day.sum(:quantity).sort_by{|product,quantity|  -quantity}
```

Comment: Fixed it: <% Sale.where(brand: current_user.brand).group(:product).by_day.sum(:quantity).sort_by{|product,quantity|  -quantity}.each do |product,quantity| %>